# Java version upgrade to 8

Tags: java, java-8

I know that similar questions have already been answered, but I have a specific question for which it would be great if someone can throw some light.
I am trying to migrate a couple of applications (desktop apps using Swing) to Java version 8. Currently the version used for compiling as well as running) is 6.

There are a large number of third party APIs (which are no longer supported) used by these two apps which are compiled using JDK 5.

I plan to compile the applications using JDK 8 but to avoid any more complications (and rework) want to keep  the 3rd party APIs as it is (compiled on version 5) even though I do have the whole source code of the APIs.

Do you think it is a good idea and what are the points I need to be careful about.

Edit :

To precise my qustion here - considering the behaviorial and source incompatiblities between Java 5 and Java 8, is it possible and probable in practical terms that an API compiled with version 5 works perfectly fine with JRE 8, but wen I try to recompile it with JDK 8, it fails with compilation errors?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I thought you said you had a >>specific<< question ... sigh.

Comment: I do have a specific question. The question is is there any advantage in terms of  time / efforts if I just keep my 3rd party APIs as it is (compiled on version 5) and just run it in JRE8  over recompiling all of them using Java 8 - am I expected to run into problems.  I do have the source code of the APIs but not knowledge of the code which means any source code modifications would come at a risk.

Comment: That is a very non-specific question.

Comment: Ok. But do you have any insights / opinion to share on this?

Comment: No - see closure reason.  I also think it could have been closed as requiring Opinion-based answers.

Answer (score 1):

Generally old code runs without problems on newer JVM.

There are very few exceptions that need to be considered.
They are listed in the [java 8 compatibility guide](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8-compatibility-guide-2156366.html).

Each incompatibility is listed with a number.

As an example `removeAll` in the class `Collection` has a different behaviour if you pass a null parameter in java 8:

> RFE 7131459
>
> Area: Core Libs / java.util.collections  Synopsis In previous
>   releases, some implementations of Collection.removeAll(Collection) and
>   retainAll(Collection) would silently ignore a null parameter if the
>   collection itself was empty. As of this release, collections will
>   consistently throw a NullPointerException if null is provided as a
>   parameter.
>
> Nature of **Incompatibility behavioral**

If your code has a complete set of unit test, you can run them using JRE of java 8 and check that none of them fails. If the coverage of unit test is complete you are quite sure that there will be no problem upgrading to java 8.

Comment: I may sound stupid, but does that mean that I can compile my apps with JDK 8 but keep other dependencies (3rd party APIs) compiled with 5 and it should normally work on JRE 8?

Comment: Yes you can. Generally it happens for older libraries

Comment: And do you think it is a better idea than recompiling the older libraries with JDK 8 as well? (I have the source code for all those libraries)

Comment: If you don't use any new feature of java 8 there is no real big difference using the already compiled version or recompiling it. Probably there will be a bigger difference using diffent compilers (OpenJDK and Oracle for example) on the same java version.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the purpose of my asking this question was more to understand if I may run into problems or issues while recompiling rather than just running them in the new JRE. In short would recompiling take significantly more time and effort than just running it in the new JRE?

Comment: @Abby there is not difference if you will run your code in a java 8 JVM. The code compiled with java 8 will not work on older version of the JVM, but if you have the same version of java used to compile and running code there is no problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105817/discussion-between-abby-and-davide-lorenzo-marino).